# When you're given a degree sequence, what is the method to draw a graph which has that degree sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

When you're given a degree sequence, what is the method to draw a graph which has that degree sequence?

Consider the degree sequence $(1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5)$.
Either draw a graph with this degree sequence of prove that no such graph exists.

NB: I'm aware that no degree sequence can contain an odd number of odd numbers. 
Also, there is at most one edge between two vertices and there cannot be an edge from a vertex which is incident to itself.

Comment: Are two vertices allowed to have more than one edge beween them?

Comment: @Arthur Nope, there is at most one edge between two vertices.

Comment: How about loops? That is can there be an edge from a vertex to itself?

Comment: @paw88789 Nope, there cannot be an edge from a vertex to itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the given sequence, if we are talking about simple graphs, no such graph exists. You can conclude that by pure logical arguments:

- We have $6$ vertices.
- Two of them have degree $5$.
- Then each of them are adjacent to every other vertices.
- Then we cannot have a vertex with degree $1$ since we already know that every vertex is adjacent to at least two vertices, namely the ones with degree $5$.
- Therefore no such graph exists.

Answer (score 7):

The answer by ArsenBerk is correct (assuming simple graphs), but since you are also asking how to *get* to that answer, here is how I found it:

It's never a bad idea to just *try* things if you're stuck. So we try to draw the graph. Well, there are six vertices, so we start by drawing them. Cool. Next, two of them have degree $5$, which is easy; no real choice involved here, so we just pick two vertices to be our degree-five vertices and draw the nine lines. From here, you can- *Wait a second!* Now each vertex has at least two edges already, but we wanted one vertex to have degree $1$. That's impossible.

Answer (score 6):

This is a well researched math problem (with answers!). The [Erdos-Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) gives and if and and only if condition on whether a degree sequence can be realized and the [Havel-Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) gives you a way to do it.

Comment: +1 for giving the general argument. I knew there was an inequality but I forgot its name so couldn't refer to it :/